# Structure of Angular / NodeJS repository which will run in docker

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, docker

We have repository with an application written in Angular.
It needs a docker container with nginx to be hosted.
The nodejs needs a docker container of nodejs so our app will be split up in 2 containers which will be linked.

So to write 2 dockerfiles (one for each image) we have to split up our folders in our repo like:

- root

  - Angular : contains dockerfile for nginx
  - NodeJS : contains dockerfile for nodejs

But the problem is they both need the package.json. (Angular for devdependencies and NodeJS for the dependencies).

Which is the best structure in the repo for your application?

Answer (score 0):

The Nginx and Nodejs containers can share a volume in Docker Compose if you like. You can use the volumes_from parameter. It will mount all of the volumes from another service or container, optionally specifying read-only access(ro) or read-write(rw). https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

```
    volumes_from:
      - service_name
      - container_name
      - service_name:rw
```

In your case, package.json can be in your Nodejs container but it can also be accessible by the Nginx container using this parameter.